# How to get list of pages indexed by Google?

Tags: asp.net, web-crawler

I have created a site twoo years ago in php and now converting it into asp.net mvc. Now I would like to get all indexed pages by Google so I can validate all these are working with new site.

I search on google using "site:mysite.com" it shows 21000 results, So how Can i get these 21000 results and validate all they are working with new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a tool that gives you a list. However one way I can think of is to keep an eye on your Google WebMasters account for errors. Any page that Google can't reach will be a page you need to look at and fix. This isn't a fast solution but it's a reliable one.

If your previous website has a structure to its urls then it should be easy to replicate that using routes in asp.Net.

Answer (score 0):

I think this topic has to be moved to webmasters section of stackexchange.

Generally what people would do with change of url is to give 301 redirect to all the new pages  from old pages (aka url rewriting).

To verify if all your links work, you can use a tool called Xenu. Being a webmaster, you might already known this. It just goes through the entire list of urls in the pages and verifies them. But in your case you want to check if all your old php links work, you can possibly get a sitemap of the existing list and do the checking by putting this sitemap page on the new site.